# Rangy : how to implement Multiple style?

Tags: javascript, rangy

im using [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/) for highlighting text in my web page.
is there a way to set multiple styles for user to choose for highlighting text ?
for example when user click on some yellow highlight, i take all of the text with getHighlightForElement() method but i dont know how to change the color class/id ?
or any other way suggestion?
thank you !

Comment: @timdown so that if timdown shows up on SO as he does pretty regularly(?) he will see this

Answer (score 0):

The code below is a simple stylesheet swapper. When you click on the "Highlight 1" button, it will load a stylesheet named "highlight1.css". The stylesheet will be swapped out when you click a different button.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="default_highlight.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="highlight">
    <script>
      function setHighlight1() {
        const highlight = document.getElementById('highlight');
        highlight.href = 'highlight1';
      }
      function setHighlight2() {
        const highlight = document.getElementById('highlight');
        highlight.href = 'highlight2';
      }
      function setHighlight3() {
        const highlight = document.getElementById('highlight');
        highlight.href = 'highlight_3.css';
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="setHighlight1()">Highlight 1</button>
    <button onclick="setHighlight2()">Highlight 2</button>
    <button onclick="setHighlight3()">Highlight 3</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: thank you but in one page there are for example 3 different yellow highlight. user click on one of them and a popup opens, then he wants to change the style ... this is my problem...

Comment: That's fine. The code changes the actual stylesheet that is loaded. If the user wants to change the style, they simply need to click on the button (like in my example). The buttons can be added into that popup.

Comment: sorry but there is times that multiple span in one highlighted text and only we can retrieve them by mentioned method. we can not simply change the style. please take a look at Rangy.